# How to get Ponter/Reference semantics in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, reference, pointers, scala-2.8

In C++ I would just take a pointer (or reference) to arr[idx].
In Scala I find myself creating this class to emulate a pointer semantic.

```
class SetTo (val arr : Array[Double], val idx : Int) {
  def apply (d : Double) { arr(idx) = d }
}
```

Isn't there a simpler way?
Doesn't Array class have a method to return some kind of reference to a particular field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays used in Scala are JVM arrays (in 2.8) and JVM arrays have no concept of a slot reference.

The best you can do is what you illustrate. But `SetTo` does not strike me as a good name. `ArraySlot`, `ArrayElement` or `ArrayRef` seem better.

Furthermore, you might want to implement `apply()` to read the slot and `update(newValue)` to replace the slot. That way instances of that class can be used on the left-hand-side of an assignment. However, both retrieving the value via `apply` and replacing it via `update` method *will* require the empty argument lists, `()`.

```
class ASlot[T](a: Array[T], slot: Int) {
  def apply(): T = a(slot);
  def update(newValue: T): Unit = a(slot) = newValue
}

scala> val a1 = Array(1, 2, 3)
a1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> val as1 = new ASlot(a1, 1)
as1: ASlot[Int] = ASlot@e6c6d7

scala> as1()
res0: Int = 2

scala> as1() = 100

scala> as1()
res1: Int = 100

scala> a1
res2: Array[Int] = Array(1, 100, 3)
```

Comment: Is there no default mutable.SeqRef or something like that? Really? Shouldn't we add it to standard library? I guess it could use mutable.Seq instead of Array.

Comment: @Alexy: That probably is better, from a readability standpoint. It crossed my mind that an implicit conversion could be used to read the value out of the referenced array slot, too.