# scala Remove (in place) all elements of a ListBuffer that meet a condition

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, listbuffer

I have a ListBuffer. I want to remove all elements that meet a certain condition.

I could iterate over it and remove each element. But what doe Scala say about mutating a list that you are iterating over? Will it work, or will it delete the wrong elements/not return all elements? (A quick attempt with the REPL suggests that yes, it will mess up)

I could repeatedly call find and then remove the found element until I don't find any more, but that sounds inefficient.

.filter will return me a new ListBuffer without the elements, but I want to do it in place.

This

```
def --= (xs: TraversableOnce[A]) : ListBuffer.this.type
Removes all elements produced by an iterator from this list buffer.
```

looks promising but I can't quite see how to use it here

How should I do this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803085/iterators-for-mutable-collections-in-scala

Comment: Scala 2.13 brings filterInPlace method to ListBuffer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this efficiently, unfortunately.  The implementation of `--=(xs: TraversableOnce[A])` is (in expanded form; the actual code is more compact)

```
xs foreach (x => this -= x) ; this
```

which is just as inefficient as doing it one at a time (i.e. it's `O(n*m)` where `n` is the length of the original list and `m` is the number of items to remove).

In general, the mutable collections don't have as full and powerful a set of methods as the immutable ones.  (That is, they have all the wonderful methods used on immutable collections, but relatively few of their own.)

So unless you're removing *very* few objects, you're probably better off filtering the list to create a new one.

Comment: "the mutable collections don't have as full and powerful a set of methods as the immutable ones.". Yes. This is a pity. Functional programming may be great, but sometimes a mutable data structure is really what I want and the relatively meagre support for multable-only ops is a bit disappointing

Answer (score 7):

You could combine the two and do the following:

```
val lb = ListBuffer(1,2,3,4,5,6)
lb --= lb.filter(_ % 2 == 0)

println(lb)
// outputs: ListBuffer(1, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Perfect. Probably being dumb, but how come that works? Does filter return an iterator rather than a list? Or does the TraversableOnce mean a list is good enough as an iterator to --=?

Comment: `TraversableOnce` is more general than an iterator.  It is a common superclass of both `Traversable` (on which all collections are based) and `Iterator`.

Comment: Thanks. The scaladoc is confusing with the description saying it takes an iterator...

Comment: It's worth noting that's not super efficient - you're producing a new listbuffer from filter, and then you're traversing the original collection AGAIN to remove the values.