# Scala 2.11 LinkedList is deprecated, what should I use?

Tags: scala, collections, linked-list

According to [the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList), `scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList` is deprecated as of the 2.11 version. Unfortunately I have found nothing to replace it with. I need an ordered collection that can remove an item from **any** index in constant time.

What should I use?

Comment: Can you confirm the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use MutableList and its iterator's `remove` method. They provide O(1) removal.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#linked_lists

Comment: I'm not following. How do you get O(1) removal from end with MutableList?

Comment: @kfer38Because it has pointer to the last element, it can remove the last element without traversing all elements.

Comment: Sorry, but MutableList's iterator does not have a `remove` method. Here's why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803085/iterators-for-mutable-collections-in-scala

Answer (score 5):

From what I understand of your problem you want to iterate through collection and change it on the fly. That is not possible with collection constructs other than (now deprecated) `scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList` or `scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList`. This kind of operation doesn't really follow the Scala collections philosophy hence `LinkedList` and `DoubleLinkedList` are deprecated now.

**However nothing stops you from using classic Java's `java.util.LinkedList` and relevant iterator in your Scala code.**

Unless you want to review your design and follow Scala's way using constructs like: `map`, `filter`, `for`, `fold`, `reduce`, etc. For example, using `filter` function you can create a new list with only relevant items.

Answer (score 1):

Hey everyone from 2021 :)
The correct answer was correct for version **2.12**, but for **2.13** - actual another one. I will quote the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html#deprecated-things-in-212-that-have-been-removed-in-213)

> collection.mutable.MutableList (was not deprecated in 2.12 but was
> considered to be an implementation detail for implementing other
> collections). Use an ArrayDeque or mutable.ListBuffer instead, or a
> List and a var ;