# Which class can be used to replace LinkedList in Scala

Tags: scala

I wish to implement this problem "Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list."

But LinkedList class is removed in Scala lastest version, May I know which class can I use now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala 2.11 LinkedList is deprecated, what should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557427/scala-2-11-linkedlist-is-deprecated-what-should-i-use)

Comment: Use List, thats a linked list under the hood anyway.

Comment: If you need quick prepand/append you can use ListBuffer, tried on number of classical algorithms. http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html